# Twitter card whitelisting issues probably because URL is inaccessible to crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, amazon-ec2, twitter-card

I have been trying to get my [website](http://www.indiaoutside.org) whitelisted for Twitter cards. Every time I apply for whitelisting I get an email saying **"The URL you provided for indiaoutside.org to use the summary_image_large card is inaccessible."**

I tried searching their community and found [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-card-not-whitelisted-because-url-is-inaccessible/37034). It is apparent that **Twitter's crawler is unable to access my website**. I am running an AWS EC2 for this website. **How do I find out if AWS is denying access to the web crawler and how do I change that?**

Answer (score 0):

I do not beleive that AWS will block a crawler. Generally it is upto you as the owner of the instance to control what ports are open and what traffic you want to accept or reject - I suspect you are having another problem.

Have you used the twitter card validator?:

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

If you can't get it to pass that test, its not going to get approved by twitter.